# Custom Currency validation - Magento using validate.js

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript, form-validation

I am looking for a way to all for custom currency validation using native magento validate.js

I have a form which allows users to add custom prices to a text field. I am using the following classes to validate the inputs:

```
validate-digits-range 

digits-range-1-10
```

The problem is the text field is pre-populated with the currency sign `£` so will not pass validation.

I have tried to adapt the `validate-currency-dollar` class but the test still fails

```
Validation.add('validate-currency-dollar', 'Please enter a valid $ amount. For example $100.00.', function(v) {
    // [$]1[##][,###]+[.##]
    // [$]1###+[.##]
    // [$]0.##
    // [$].##
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) ||  /^\$?\-?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|0(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$/.test(v)
});
```

Has anyone done this before can share some advice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed a bit regular expression

```
/^[\$£]?\-?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|0(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$/
```

Try it instead of standard ones.